# Verify the solution to a Bessel's equation has finite length or not

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, stability-in-odes

Consider the following Bessel's equation
$$\ddot{x}(t) + \frac{3}{t}\dot{x}(t) + x(t) = 0$$
with initial condition $x(0)=1$ and $\dot{x}(0)=0$. From WolframAlpha, we know the solution is given by
$$x(t) = \frac{2J_1(t)}{t}$$
where $J_1(t)$ is the Bessel's function of the first kind with degree $1$. It is easy to see that $x(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$. My question is that can we prove the trajectory of the solution $x(t)$ has finite length, i.e.,
$$\int_0^\infty |\dot{x}(t)| dt <\infty$$

---

I find that the trajectory is oscillating, so it seems that the trajectory length is pretty long, but since we have extra $1/t$ factor, maybe it makes the solution converge fast enough so that the length is indeed finite. Any ideas to prove or disprove would be helpful.

---

My trial:

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty |\dot{x}(t)| dt &= \int_0^\infty \left|\frac{2J_1'(t)}{t}-\frac{2J_1(t)}{t^2}\right|dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \left|\frac{J_0(t)-J_2(t)}{t}-\frac{2J_1(t)}{t^2}\right|dt
\end{align}
Thus, a sufficient condition for the above quantity to be finite is
$$\frac{J_0(t)}{t},\; \frac{J_2(t)}{t} \text{ and } \frac{J_1(t)}{t^2} \text{ are integrable on } \mathbb{R}_+.$$
From WolframAlpha I know $|J_1(t)|\leq 1$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$, so the last term above is obviously integrable. It suffices to check the first two are integrable. I guess $J_0(t)$ and $J_2(t)$ will have similar behavior at infinity, but I don't know how that implies integrability of $J_0(t)/t$ and $J_2(t)/t$.

Comment: How is the trajectory a spiral?

Comment: @K.defaoite Sorry for a misleading description, I have corrected it know.

Comment: The answer should more or less be contained in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/55732).

Comment: @prets Thanks for the link. Indeed, then it seems that $J_n(t)/t$ is integrable for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.